# Monastery or Temple in California

Tags: monastery, temples

Hope you all doing excellent!
Would like to know if there's any monastery or Theravada temple in San Francisco, OC or LA?
I know there's one in Redwood Valley, but it's a lil too far off.
Pls share, if you happen to know any nearby.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing specific to Theravada nearby (other than what you found in Redwood Valley, which I'm guessing is [Abhayagiri](https://www.abhayagiri.org/home/)), but just in case it is helpful, here are some other monasteries and temples that are somewhat close:

- [Berkeley Buddhist Monastery](http://www.berkeleymonastery.org)
- [Buddha Gate Monastery](http://buddhagate.org)
- [Wat Mongkolratanaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wat_Mongkolratanaram), a Thai Buddhist temple
- [Berkeley Buddhist Temple](http://www.berkeleysangha.org)

Also less than an hour away is also the [Insight Meditation Center](http://www.insightmeditationcenter.org), which is neither a monastery nor a temple, but is very much rooted in Theravada teachings (so maybe worth mentioning).

Answer (score 2):

I've attended Vipassana intensive retreats at Tathagata Meditation Center in San Jose, a Mahasi style center. I found the atmosphere conducive to advanced meditation practice and the other yogis who practice there were equally intense/not many beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/search.php?keyword=&search=Search&country_id=0&province_id=26&tradition%5B%5D=theravada)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Worldwide Mahamevnawa Branches](http://mahamevnawa.lk/mahamevnawa-branches-of-abroad/) there's a 
"Mahamevnawa Meditation Monastery of California" in Torrance (in the region of Los Angeles).